# Overriding ToString, Equals,.. in Entities when using Entity Framework

Tags: visual-studio, entity-framework, overriding

I would like to override `ToString`, `Equals` and `GetHashCode` methods of an *Entity* generated by the model of the Entity Framework.

**What could be the best way of doing this?**

Now I'm manually editing the `___Model.Designer.cs` file that generates the model, but everytime I change the model, of course, I lost these changes.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Every Entity is defined as a partial class, so that you can define an additional partial class to extend the Entity with additional properties or methods.

Lets say you have defined an Entity `Person` in your EntityModel.

Now you can create a new class file name `Person.cs` in your project. Within the class file you define a

```
public partial class Person{
   // Here you can add your additional functionality or method overrides
}
```

The partial class must be defined in the same namespace and the same assembly as the `Person` Entity.

The new class file is unaffected by changes in the EntityModel (Only if you remove the Entity or change properties, then your partial class might need an update).

Comment: Thank you very much. Don't know how I missed it ;)